# Plot raster time series (rts) object with Levelplot R after coercing to raster object

Tags: r, raster, levelplot, rastervis

I would like to display the results in a raster times series object (rts) using levelplot function in rasterVis.

Here is a short code frome rts package:

```
    library(raster)
 library(rasterVis)
    library(rts)
    path <- system.file("external", package="rts")
    lst <- list.files(path=path,pattern='.asc$',full.names=TRUE)
    r <- stack(lst)
    d <- c("2000-02-01","2000-03-01","2000-04-01","2000-05-01") # corresponding dates to 4 rasters
    d <- as.Date(d)

    # creating a RasterStackTS object:
    rt <- rts(r,d)
```

To coerce from .rts to raster I used:

```
r=rt@raster



 proj=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=NAD27 +no_defs +ellps=clrk66 +nadgrids=@conus,@alaska,@ntv2_0.gsb,@ntv1_can.dat")

    proj4string(r) <- proj
wgs84.p4s <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +ellps=GRS80 +no_defs")
```

reprojecting `r` from `UTM coordinates to latlong coordinates`

```
rx <- projectRaster(from=r, crs=wgs84.p4s@projargs, method="ngb")

writeRaster(rt, file="myfile100.tif", format="GTiff", overwrite=TRUE)
ras = raster("myfile100.tif")
```

How can I read all 4 layers in `myfile100.tif`? 
`ras = raster("myfile100.tif")` reads only `layer 1`

```
proj4string(ras) <- proj
plot(ras)
levelplot(ras)
```

I get this error:

```
Error in projectExtent(from, projto) : cannot do this transformation
In addition: Warning message:
In rgdal::rawTransform(projfrom, projto, nrow(xy), xy[, 1], xy[,  :
  146 projected point(s) not finite
```

How can I get around this?
Maybe there is even a shorter and reasonable way to do this.
Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: When reading in use `stack()` and it will read the tif in as a stack. Pondering the rest of your question.

Comment: @Badger ras = stack("myfile100.tif")  reads all layers. Great!

Comment: Try `rx <- projectRaster(from=r, crs=wgs84.p4s, method="ngb")`, I've never used the @ part that you declared but its not to say that it is incorrect, I'm just curious of the behaviour.

Comment: @Badger I got the same error using `rx <- projectRaster(from=r, crs=wgs84.p4s, method="ngb")`

Comment: You should take a look at the `setZ` and `getZ` functions provided by the `raster` package. Maybe you could use them instead of the `rts` package. On the other hand, I think the error is due to the projection definition you are using. Are you sure that is the correct proj4 string? [This page](http://spatialreference.org/) will be useful to check it.

Comment: @OscarPerpiñán I find `setZ` ,`zApply` and `getZ` very useful. But looks like these functions are still under development? How can I use `zApply` to sum `rasterStack` object with 30mins time step to daily time step? Then I can easily generate my maps using levelplot

Comment: You can use them safely. In my opinion, they are stable functions. I should suggest R. Hijmans to remove the warning about being under development. Regarding your question about the usage of `zApply`, please open a new question because comments are not the right place. Meanwhile, you have an example [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2013-April/018136.html).